# Create variable only if Firebase database does not exist

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating an application that starts the home activity and creates the methods in the Firebase database. This does it correctly but each user has a variable called `acoins` and I want this every time someone enters if it already exists that is not set to 0 that stays with the value that has.

This is the code I have :

```
databaseRef.child("users/" + user.getDisplayName() + "/acoins").setValue(0);
```

­

```
private void setUserData(FirebaseUser user) {
    nameTextView.setText(user.getDisplayName());
    emailTextView.setText(user.getEmail());
    idTextView.setText(user.getUid());
    Glide.with(this).load(user.getPhotoUrl()).into(photoImageVie‌​w);
    DatabaseReference databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    databaseRef.child("users/" + user.getDisplayName()).setValue(user.getEmail());
    databaseRef.child("users/" + user.getDisplayName() + "/acoins").setValue(0);
}
```

Comment: What condition for a user, are you using to set value of acoins to zero?

Comment: This is my code    
private void setUserData(FirebaseUser user) {
        nameTextView.setText(user.getDisplayName());
        emailTextView.setText(user.getEmail());
        idTextView.setText(user.getUid());
        Glide.with(this).load(user.getPhotoUrl()).into(photoImageView);


        DatabaseReference databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        databaseRef.child("users/" + user.getDisplayName()).setValue(user.getEmail());
        databaseRef.child("users/" + user.getDisplayName() + "/acoins").setValue(0);
    }

Comment: i cant understand it, put it in question by editing

Comment: basically what I want is to only execute the creation in firebase if these do not exist

Answer (score -1):

Try this in setUserData() method

```
    DatabaseReference databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(); 
        DatabaseReference dr = ref.child("users").child(user.getDisplayName).child("acoins");

         dr.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
         @Override
         public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Long acoins1 = (Long)dataSnapshot.getValue();
            if(acoins1 != 0)
              {//create toast or anything here
              }
            else{
                 databaseRef.child("users/" + user.getDisplayName() + "/acoins").setValue(0);
               }
         }

         @Override
         public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

         }
         });
```

Comment: I have assumed that acoins is already there so didn't created the code to check it.